# How prove there exists a real number $y$ with $0<y<1$ such that $a_0+a_1y+\cdots+a_ny^n=0.$

Tags: analysis

Suppose that the real numbers $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n$ and $x,$ with $0<x<1,$ satisfy $$\frac{a_0}{1-x}+\frac{a_1}{1-x^2}+\cdots+\frac{a_n}{1-x^{n+1}}=0.$$Prove that there exists a real number $y$ with $0<y<1$ such that $$a_0+a_1y+\cdots+a_ny^n=0.$$

My try: let
$$f(x)=a_{n}x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{1}x+a_{0}$$
then 
$$f(0)=a_{0}$$
$$f(1)=a_{0}+a_{1}+\cdots+a_{n}$$

But How can prove 
$$f(0)f(1)<0?$$

Thank you

Comment: Where does this question come from?

Comment: This was A3 of the 2013 putnam exam

Answer (score 5):

Let $$
f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k z^k
\quad\text{ and }\quad
g(z) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{1-z^{k+1}}$$

Since $0 < x < 1$, we can rewrite $g(x)$ as an absolutely converging power series.

$$g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{1-x^{k+1}}
= \sum_{k=0}^n \left( a_k \sum_{p=0}^\infty x^{(k+1)p}\right)
= \sum_{p=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^{kp} \right) x^p
= \sum_{p=0}^\infty f(x^p) x^p
$$
In the RHS of above expression, all the $x^p > 0$. 
If some $f(x^p)$ are non-zero and all non-zero $f(x^p)$ are having the same sign, $g(x)$ cannot sum to $0$. So there is either a pair
non-negative integers $r, s$ such that $r < s$ and $f(x^r) f(x^s) < 0$
or all $f(x^q) = 0$.

In the first case, IVT tell us there is $y \in (x^s, x^r) \subset (0,1)$ such that $f(y) = 0$. In the second case, we can take $y = x$ and $f(y) = 0$.